# Create JS MotionGuide Invalid Path

Tags: javascript, createjs, tweenjs

I am trying to sequence together a series of points for a createjs Tween within Adobe Animate. The idea is for the 'player' object to follow a predetermined set of points, but the player can move backward and forward along the path by clicking on the points, so the array of coordinates that the player needs to travel through can change each time. I have the coordinates just fine, but I am getting errors about the path being invalid, and to check the documentation for valid path details (http://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/MotionGuidePlugin.html) where I see no details about path validity.

Can anyone tell me why this works (player animates fine):

```
var testArr = [7,278, 240,278, 408,327];
createjs.Tween.get(player).to({guide:{path:testArr}},1000);
```

but the following does not (player does not animate, throws error: **Uncaught invalid 'path' data, please see documentation for valid paths**) :

```
var testArr = [7,278, 240,278, 408,327, 609,327];
createjs.Tween.get(player).to({guide:{path:testArr}},1000);
```

I have gotten all sorts of animations working just fine, but the MotionGuide plugin seems to have issues with the coordinates I am passing in. I've done a lot of testing and cannot seem to find a pattern to what makes a set of coordinates valid or invalid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd answer in case anyone else had this issue.

It seems as though entering an odd amount of coordinate pairs fixes the issue, instead of an even number of coordinate pairs.

I presume this has to do with n number of curveTo calls happening behind the scenes.